# Counting database entries by field type in django

Tags: django, count, unique, models

I have a model in my django project called "change" and it has a field called "change_type". There are multiple values within the change_type field to include "move", "new", "edit" and others with new types being added randomly over any given period of time. I am currently using normal django queries to select groups of entries within the change model.

Is there a quick method to determine what unique entries are in the change_type field? Is there a quick method to return a count of each entry type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting it together:

```
 occurrences = {}
 change_types = Change.objects.values_list('change_type', flat=True).distinct()

 for type in change_types:
     occurrences[type] = Change.objects.filter(change_type=type).count()
```

Answer (score 3):

After finding the solution, it is really simple.

```
Change.objects.all().values('change_type').distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/ maybe that will be helpful for You.

Answer (score 0):

This can now be much more effectively implemented using [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/):

`Change.objects.values('change_type').annotate(Count('change_‌​type'))`

The output contain `change_type__count` field for each respective `change_type`.